# Where can I find a full list of errors that Facebook might return as part of an oauthResult?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm looking to map errors to useful user feedback information, and I'd like to kill all the possible birds with one giant stone - but I can't seem to find a list of these errors. Are they posted somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth/errors/